# Identifying specific strings and checking subsequent rows for another string

Tags: pandas, loops, if-statement

I have the following DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['A','.','.','X','.','.'],
    '2':['.','.','.','.','A','.'],
    '3':['.','.','.','.','.','.'],
    '4':['.','.','.','.','.','X']})
```

I want to identify all instances where 'A' occurs and check to see if 'X' occurs within the next 3 rows.

After doing that I would like to execute a command based on these conditions.

an example of what I am trying to do would be...

```
for i, idx in df.iterrows():
    if idx == A:
        if X exists within next 3 rows:
            x= idx['1']
            y= idx['2']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: within the next 3 rows **and the same column** or in **any** column?

Comment: It'll be within another column (that will stay constant). Thanks

Comment: check if my answer is what you want

Comment: Sorry not quite, I apologise if its not clear, not sure if this helps... if A exists anywhere (all instances): and X exists within 3 rows then (execute command)

Comment: what would help is a clear example with the matching output (use simple letters like in my answer for clarity)

Comment: Ok I've tried again. If it doesn't make sense this time then I apologise, thank you for your time. I do not know the solution which is why I'm asking for help

Comment: why don't you explain how my solution does not work? ONce you have the final mask you can use it to do whatever you want, such as finding your x/y value. What are the commands you want to perform?

Comment: Also, in your example do we agree that rows 0 and 4 would match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that the other answer could work if you were to explain what you really want to do. It would be more efficient as iterating over rows is **slow**.

However, here is a solution based on `iterrows`:

```
mask = df.eq('X').any(1)
mask = mask.where(mask).bfill(limit=3).fillna(False)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'A' in row.values and mask[idx]:
        x = row['1']
        y = row['2']
        print(f'row {idx} matches: {x=}, {y=}')
```

example input (slightly different from yours):

```
   1  2  3  4
0  A  .  .  .
1  .  .  .  .
2  .  .  A  .
3  .  .  .  .
4  X  A  .  .
5  .  .  X  .
```

output:

```
row 2 matches: x='.', y='.'
row 4 matches: x='X', y='A'
```

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you want to identify the cells where there is a value **A** and if within the next 3 rows, there is also a value **X**

I will use a more visual example for clarity (A/X/.):

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  A  .  .  A  .  A
1  .  .  X  .  A  .
2  .  A  .  .  .  A
3  .  X  .  X  .  X
4  X  .  .  .  .  .
```

One can use `eq` to find the searched values and `where`+`bfill(limit=3)`+`.fillna` to extend the second mask to the previous lines.

```
# mask for the A
m1 = df.eq('A')

# mask for the X in the next 3 lines
m2 = df.eq('X')
m2 = m2.where(m2).bfill(limit=3).fillna(False)

# example of how to use the masks: replacing A with O
df[m1&m2] = 'O'
```

Example output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  A  .  .  O  .  O
1  .  .  X  .  A  .
2  .  O  .  .  .  O
3  .  X  .  X  .  X
4  X  .  .  .  .  .
```

###### checking X for any column

Just change the second mask to:

```
m2 = df.eq('X').any(1)
m2 = m2.where(m2).bfill(limit=3).fillna(False)
```

output with this mask:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  O  .  .  O  .  O
1  .  .  X  .  O  .
2  .  O  .  .  .  O
3  .  X  .  X  .  X
4  X  .  .  .  .  .
```